# Tensorflow Scalar Multiplication with Batches

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, linear-algebra, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to create a tensorflow layer that takes in n inputs, n-1 are data points and the last is a weight vector of length n-1. Each of the (i in n-1) data points are then multiplied by the value stored in index i of the weight vector. The result of the weighted datapoints is then accumulated and returned as a single datapoint. The problem I am having is doing this efficiently in TensorFlow with batches. Because of the extra batch dimension I end up needing to multiply n-1 tensors of shape (None 9, 256, 256, 1) by n-1 a tensors of shape (None, ).

To achieve this I have tried to make use of the functions `tf.math.multiply(tensor, weights)`, `tf.math.scalar_mul(weights1, tensor1)`, and `tf.linalg.matvec(tensor1, weights1)` The code follows:

```
class LinearCombination(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LinearCombination, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Ensure that the input shape matches the expected shape
        print(input_shape)

        num_tensors = len(input_shape[0])
        num_weights = input_shape[1][1]
        assert num_tensors == num_weights, f"Number of tensors{num_tensors} and number of weights{num_weights} must match."

        super(LinearCombination, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Multiply each tensor by its corresponding weight and sum them up
        print("\n\n\n\nlayer called")
        tensors = inputs[0]
        tensor1 = tensors[0]
        tensor2 = tensors[1]
        tensor3 = tensors[2]

        print(f"\ntensors: {tensors}")
        print(f"t1{tensor1}")
        print(f"t2{tensor2}")
        print(f"t3{tensor3}\n\n")

        weights = inputs[1]
        weights1 = weights[:, 0]
        #weights1 = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(weights1, axis=-1), axis=-1), axis=-1)

        weights2 = weights[:, 1]
        #weights2 = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(weights2, axis=-1), axis=-1), axis=-1)

        weights3 = weights[:, 2]
        #weights3 = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(weights3, axis=-1), axis=-1), axis=-1)


        print(f"\n\nweights: {weights}")
        print(f"w1{weights1}")
        print(f"w2{weights2}")
        print(f"w3{weights3}\n\n")



        #tensor1 = tf.math.multiply(tensor1, weights1)
        #tensor2 = tf.math.multiply(tensor2, weights2)
        #tensor3 = tf.math.multiply(tensor3, weights3)
        #tensor1 = tf.math.scalar_mul(weights1, tensor1)
        #tensor2 = tf.math.scalar_mul(weights2, tensor2)
        #tensor3 = tf.math.scalar_mul(weights3, tensor3)
        #tensor1 = tf.linalg.matvec(tensor1, weights1)
        #tensor2 = tf.linalg.matvec(tensor2, weights2)
        #tensor3 = tf.linalg.matvec(tensor3, weights3)
        print(f"\nresults:")
        print(f"r1{tensor1}")
        print(f"r2{tensor2}")
        print(f"r3{tensor3}\n\n")


        out = tf.math.add(tensor1, tensor2)
        out = tf.math.add(tensor3, out)
        print(f"final output: {out}")

        return out

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0][1]  # Output shape matches the shape of each input tensor
```

with all the multiplication commented out tensors keep the right shape the print statements from the call function follow:

```
tensors: [<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(None, 9, 256, 256, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(None, 9, 256, 256, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0' shape=(None, 9, 256, 256, 1) dtype=float32>]
t1Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 9, 256, 256, 1), dtype=float32)
t2Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None, 9, 256, 256, 1), dtype=float32)
t3Tensor("Placeholder_2:0", shape=(None, 9, 256, 256, 1), dtype=float32)




weights: Tensor("Placeholder_3:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)
w1Tensor("linear_combination/strided_slice:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
w2Tensor("linear_combination/strided_slice_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
w3Tensor("linear_combination/strided_slice_2:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32)



results:
r1Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 9, 256, 256, 1), dtype=float32)
r2Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None, 9, 256, 256, 1), dtype=float32)
r3Tensor("Placeholder_2:0", shape=(None, 9, 256, 256, 1), dtype=float32)


final output: Tensor("linear_combination/Add_1:0", shape=(None, 9, 256, 256, 1), dtype=float32)
```

it would also be great to not hardcode the fact that we have three tensors.

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) to achieve such a maneuver. Here's the updated `call()` function:

```py
    def call(self, inputs):
        # Multiply each tensor by its corresponding weight and sum them up
        print("\n\n\n\nlayer called")
        tensors = inputs[0]  # List of M tensor with shape (BATCH, 9, 256, 256, 1)
        weights = inputs[1]  # Tensor with shape (BATCH, M)
        
        # [(BATCH, 1, 9, 256, 256, 1)] ==concat=> (BATCH, M, 9, 256, 256, 1)
        big_tensor = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(t, axis=1) for t in tensors], axis=1)
        out = tf.einsum('nmabcd,nm->nabcd', big_tensor, weights)
        
        print(f"final output: {out}")

        return out
```

Comment: tf.einsum looks like it should do what I want it to, but the provided code gives the following error
```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "linear_combination" (type LinearCombination).

out = tf.einsum('nmabcd,nm->nabcd', weights, big_tensor)

    ValueError: Shape must be rank 6 but is rank 2
      for 0th input and equation: nmabcd,nm->nabcd for '{{node linear_combination/einsum/Einsum}} = Einsum[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, equation="nmabcd,nm->nabcd"](Placeholder_3, linear_combination/concat)' with input shapes: [?,3], [?,3,9,256,256,1].
```
Any more suggestions?

Comment: Oh sorry I seem to have swapped the args. Edited

Comment: Thank you so much! The above solution works, but if you want to do them one at a time (not sure why you would ever do this) the modification to my code is
```
tensor1 = tf.einsum('ijklm,i->ijklm', tensor1, weights1)
tensor2 = tf.einsum('ijklm,i->ijklm', tensor2, weights2)
tensor3 = tf.einsum('ijklm,i->ijklm', tensor3, weights3)
```

Comment: Glad it works! It would be appreciated if the answer can be marked as accepted. I think here the [broadcast rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) might be an interesting read.